# After adding arrays together, is there a way to know which elements came from which parent array?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

Here's the JSON i'm working with:

```
{
"featured": [
    {
        "name": "Featured Show number 1",
        "id": "123",
        "slug": "featured-show-number-one",
        "description": "This is an item description for show number 1"
    },
    {
        "name": "Featured Show number 2",
        "id": "456",
        "slug": "featured-show-nubmer-tow",
        "description": "This is an item description for show number 2"
    }
 ],
 "nonfeatured": [
    {
        "name": "Show number 3",
        "id": "789",
        "slug": "show-number-three",
        "description": "This is an item description for show number 3"
    },
    {
        "name": "Show number 4",
        "id": "135",
        "slug": "show-number-four",
        "description": "This is an item description for show number 4"
    }
  ]
}
```

What I am trying to figure out is after I parse this JSON using two data models, one for "Featured" and one for "Nonfeatured", looping through each show and adding it to an array, I need to add the arrays of shows together to create one array containing all the shows. However, I need to keep track of which shows are featured and which ones are non featured from the single array. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: it depends on wether your data models are structs or classes. Can you show them too? When you just want to know if a show is featured, a quick solution would be to add a `isFeatured` bool to your show model and set it when creating it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer to your specific question here is 'no'. The result of adding array A and array B (where both contain the same types) is A + B; there is no metadata providing any kind of source information.

But that is not to say that you couldn't accomplish the same thing by changing the model slightly. One option would be to add an extra boolean flag to the model called `isFeatured` or similar. Or you could 'future-proof' any work by using an enumeration of source lists containing `featured`, `non-featured` plus anything else you may require later.

To take the first example, an option would be to add the boolean field and then call code similar to below prior to 'summing' the arrays.

```
arrayA.forEach { $0.isFeatured = true }
arrayB.forEach { $0.isFeatured = false }
let arrayC = arrayA + arrayB
```

Then each element in the summed array will tell you its source list.

Comment: Ah I like both of these answers. Very creative. Great job. Thanks!